# Question on Set Projection and its projected set's properties

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

For an arbitrary set $E \subseteq R^{1}$, consider its projection $E_{1}$ on the x-axis, which is defined as follows:
$$x \in E_{1} \Leftrightarrow \exists y\in R^{1}$$ such that $(x,y) \in E$.

I am trying to justify whether the following statements are right or wrong.

a) If E is open in $R^{2}$, then $E_{1}$ is open in $R^{1}$.

b) If E is closed in $R^{2}$, then $E_{1}$ is closed in $R^{1}$.

c) If E is compact in $R^{2}$, then $E_{1}$ is compact in $R^{1}$.

What tools should I use to tackle this type of problem? Any tip is greatly helpful. Thank you!

Comment: What is $R^1$? What are your thoughts?

Comment: If $R^1 = \mathbb{R}$, shouldn't $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ if you want to project onto the horizontal axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the linear map $P(x) = x_1$, then $E_1 = P(E)$.

If we stick with the Euclidean norm we see that
$P(B(x,\epsilon)) = B(P(x), \epsilon)$ (The balls are in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ respectively).

Consider the closed set $E = \{x | x_1 x_2 = 1 \}$. What is $P(E)$?

Note that $P$ is continuous, so if $E$ is compact, what can you say about $P(E)$?

Comment: a) and c) are true, b) is false. For b) consider $\{(x,y:xy=1\}$.

Comment: I believe that is the content of my answer?